# Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop & Taskbars

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a spare drive and don't like the desktop & taskbars. How do I change them to the ones I have on version 10.04?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to use **gnome-classic**.  If you don't to like the style of Unity, avoid Gnome3, as they are similar.

[IBM Explanation](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/netcooltips/entry/how_to_return_to_classic_gnome_in_ubuntu_12_04_precise12?lang=en)

[OMGUbuntu Explanation](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-12-04-its-like-nothing-ever-changed)